# round control in javafx

Tags: javafx, checkbox, rounding

I have a question. How can I make a circle checkbox in JavaFX? "-fx-background-radius" doesn`t work for me, also I want to when mouse is over checkbox to display a short describe for what this checkbox is create. How can I solved this? Thanks for helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For a `CheckBox` with rounded corners you would use CSS. It is helpful to look at the [JavaFX CSS Reference Guide](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html) when you need to know what you can style from CSS. For instance, the [section](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/doc-files/cssref.html#checkbox) for `CheckBox` tells us there is a substructure; this includes a `StackPane` with the styleclass of `box`. It is this `StackPane` that is the "physical box" in the UI and what you want to round the corners of. In you're CSS file you'd have something like:

```
.check-box .box {
  -fx-background-radius: /* enter you're desired radius here */;
}
```

Then you'd add the CSS file to your `Scene` via [`getStylesheets().add(...)`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/Scene.html#getStylesheets()).

You also want to know how to display some information about the `CheckBox` when the mouse hovers over it, correct? To do this you would use a [`Tooltip`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/javafx/scene/control/Tooltip.html).

```
CheckBox box = new CheckBox("Choose me!");
box.setTooltip(new Tooltip("I do something!"));
```